# Laravel - InvalidArgumentException view not found exception

Tags: php, view, laravel-blade, invalidargumentexception

I have a forgot password button on login page , also i have a view for reset password but getting below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTAfA.png)

refer below for location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zg4n.png)

**My controller file code :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset emails and
    | includes a trait which assists in sending these notifications from
    | your application to your users. Feel free to explore this trait.
    |
    */

    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

Please find the file used by controller is below //

**It uses SendsPasswordResetEmails :
**

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

trait SendsPasswordResetEmails
{
    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the email for the given request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed authentication credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('email');
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a successful password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($response)], 200)
                    : back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    protected function sendResetLinkFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return back()
                ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker();
    }
}
```

I have attached images related to the error and path please let me know if anyone can help me with this

I tried alot to get this work but no use

Comment: It looks like your path is actually `backend.auth.passwords.email`

Answer (score -1):

In your `ForgotPasswordController.php` add this:

```
public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        return view('backend.auth.passwords.email');
    }
```

This way you're overriding the function from the trait